# Add entity to entities collection?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

https://developers.google.com/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/entities

I want to add an array of entities to an entities collection, but the entities collection (as you can see in the reference) requires i add them by type, ie. entities.add_edge(). What's the best way to do this for an array of mixed types?

Here's a snippet - the second last line isnt valid (a generic .add doesnt exist)

```
layers.each do |layer|
    layerEnts = []
    entities.each { |e| layerEnts << e if layer == (e.layer) }
    layerGroup = entities.add_group
    layerGroup.name = layer.name
    layerGroup.entities.add(layerEnts)
end
```

Comment: You want to group existing entities by layer - is that it? Or, do you create all the entities yourself? If you are creating all the geometry yourself it's better to add them directly into the target context instead of grouping them later. (this differs from what you normally do when you use the SU UI to model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call methods in a dynamic way using [**send**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

Assuming that you can get the type doing `layer.type` this should solve your problem.

```
layerEnts.each do |l|
  type = l.typename.downcase
  layerGroup.entities.send("add_#{type}".to_sym, l)
end
```

**UPDATE:** Just reading the documentation seems that there is actually a method to get the type, it's typename and seems it's camel cased so we need to downcase it.

https://developers.google.com/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/entity#typename

---

Also it seems there are types with more than one word so you need some underscores in there. Here is a solution

```
layerEnts.each do |l|
  type = l.typename.gsub(/(.)([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').downcase
  layerGroup.entities.send("add_#{type}".to_sym, l)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems there are a few peculiarities to the different methods but this has put me on the right track.

Comment: No - do NOT use #typename to determine the type of entity - it's dead slow as it does string comparison. Since you iterate entities which can be millions you want to avoid handling strings. Instead test the class - #is_a?() or #kind_of?()

Comment: For further reading on why and examples of performance impact, see this writeup on the topic: http://www.thomthom.net/thoughts/2011/12/never-ever-use-typename/

Answer (score 1):

When you add a group you *can* specify a set of existing entities to be added to that group.

```
layers.each do |layer|
  layerEnts = []
  entities.each { |e| layerEnts << e if layer == (e.layer) }
  layerGroup = entities.add_group(layerEnts)
  layerGroup.name = layer.name
end
```

But **note**! Moving entities around between contexts like this is prone to crash if done incorrectly - and doing it incorrectly is easy to do - SU doesn't do much safeguarding here.

Only ever use `entities.add_group(ents)` when `entities` is the `model.active_entities` and `ents` are entities within the `model.active_entities`.

And, I'm not 100% sure here, there might be issues if you try to group a face without also also adding it's edges. (This would need testing.)

If your plugin created the geometry you want to group then you would be better of adding them directly to the target group - instead of adding them into one context and then grouping then later on. It avoids so many potential issues, crashes - and is much faster.

If you described the more abstract purpose of your plugin or feature it might be that the answer is something completely different.